# Is the complex structure on a del-Pezzo surface a regular complex structure?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, gromov-witten-theory

Let $(X, \omega, J)$ be a compact symplectic manifold with an almost complex structure. Fix some homology class $\beta \in H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})$. An almost 
complex structure $J$ is said to be $\textit{regular}$ for some $J$-holomorphic curve 
$u$  (that represents $\beta$) if the linearization of the $\overline{\partial}$ operator is surjective (at $u$).

$\textbf{Question}:$ Is the standard almost complex structure on a del-Pezzo 
surface a regular almost complex structure?

$\textbf{Remark}:$ One needs the complex structure to be regular in order 
to conclude that the moduli space of non multiply covered holomorphic maps 
has the right dimension (and to compute the Gromov Witten invariants). 
Since the genus zero Gromov-Witten invariants of del-Pezzo surfaces are 
well known (see the paper by Kontsevic-Mannin http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/WithManinCohFT.pdf and the paper by Pnadharipande-Gottsche http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9611012), I would imagine this is a 
well known fact.

$\textbf{Added Later:}$ Suppose $u:\mathbb{P}^1 \longrightarrow X$ is a degree 
$\beta$ map. Consider $u^* TX \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 $. By Grothendick's 
theorem this splits holomorphically as a sum of two line bundles 
$L_1 \oplus L_2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. If one can show that 
$c_1(L_1) >= -1$ and $c_1(L_2) >= -1$ then the linearization of $\overline {\partial} $ at $u$ is surjective (this is Lemma 3.3.1 in McDuff and Salamon).

Is there an immediate way to see why the two Chern numers are greater than or equal to $-1$?

Comment: What is the linearization of the $\overline{\partial }$ operator? I thought $\overline{\partial }$ was linear.

Comment: Dear Ritwik, How is this different from your previous questions about Del Pezzo surfaces?  As I always do, I direct you to the Ph.D. thesis of Damiano Testa, where he proves that the moduli spaces of non-multiple cover rational curves with specified curve class on Del Pezzo surfaces of degree $\geq 2$ have the expected dimension and that they are irreducible.

Comment: @Jason: I will carefully look at Testa's thesis; but I am asking a slightly different question. I am not asking if the moduli space has the expected dimension; I am asking if the linearization of the d bar operator is surjective. If the answer to my question is yes, then it implies the moduli space has the right dimension, but I would imagine not the other way round. I gather from your remark that Testa actually proves linearization of d bar is surjective (or rather the complex structure is regular). I apologize for asking this hastily without going through the reference you gave earlier.

Comment: @abx: $\overline{\partial}$ is not linear; it is a section of an infinite dimensional bundle. The linearization is basically the covariant derivative of this section.

Comment: @Ritwik: For a continuous family of Fredholm operators, the dimension of the cokernel is upper semicontinuous.  Thus, the subset where the operator is surjective is open.  So to prove that small perturbations of the d-bar operator are surjective, it suffices to prove this for the usual d-bar operator for holomorphic curves. For immersed holomorphic curves, the cokernel is the same as the first cohomology group of the normal bundle.  For non-multiple covers on a del Pezzo surface, the normal bundle is a line bundle of degree $\geq -1$, thus has vanishing first cohomology.

Comment: @Jason: how did you conclude that the degree of the normal bundle is >=-1?

Comment: @Jason: could you just look at the last edit I made. Was your last remark basically following that idea? Your remark about the degree of the normal bundle being greater than or equal to -1 seemed to suggest you are using that reasoning.

Comment: @Ritwik.  For an immersion, the derivative map $du$ is an embedding of $T\mathbb{P}^1$ in $u^*TX$, and the cokernel is the normal bundle.  Thus the degree of the normal bundle is $\text{deg}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(u^*TX) - \text{deg}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(T\mathbb{P}^1) = \text{deg}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(u^*T_X) - 2$.  Since $u^*TX$ has positive degree, the degree of the normal bundle is at least $-1$.